# cashier check deposited and available on my account

Tags: cashier-check

Somebody payed me with a cashier check from WELL FARGO BANK and it got deposited on my account at BANK OF AMERICA. The total amount is already available since 5 days.

As I do not trust the person and there are so many strange stories about cashier checks I am afraid that the person could ask the money back !! Is it possible that the person could tell any lie to the bank WELL FARGO and ask the money back ?

I also read something like there are some fraudulent checks !!

Please if anybody could tell me if there is no more danger to the money I got from this CASHIER CHECK ???
I contacted my oficial at BANK OF AMERICA but I got no answer at all !! ....

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that the check you have deposited is a fraudulent document. Your bank may eventually discover this and remove the funds thus deposited. It is wise for you to not spend those funds for at least 30 days, longer if possible. The danger is for those who spend the deposited funds, which when removed from the account, leave the bank balance unexpectedly and dangerously low.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !! How I can find out if the cashier check is a fraudulent document or not ?

Comment: The bank will determine that it is a counterfeit or similarly fraudulent document and notify you that the money no longer exists in your account!

Comment: If you have a real reason to suspect the document is counterfeit, it may be worth telling your bank about your suspicions. That will reduce the likelihood that you are suspected of being involved in the fraud.

Comment: I am living outside the US and I feel very unsure about dealing with checks in the US as there are so many stories about people loosing their money by getting paid with checks. I get so afraid to hear about a fraudulent check. How  it is possible that I have already since 6 days now the money on my account and suddenly I can get told that it would be a fraudulent check !! ??

Comment: Why the bank can not find it out at least in 3 days ? Are this checks so perfectly made ? There should be a way of getting sure about it.

Comment: I contacted last week already the lady who attended me when I opened my account with BANK OF AMERICA but I did not get any answer !!

Comment: Fred_dot_u , Thanx for ur answer !! In how many days the bank should find out if it is or not a fraudulent check ? So I can say to my client that I will give to him the product he bought after this amount of days !!

Answer (score 1):

While it is true that a cashiers cheque may be fraudulent, and fraudulent cashiers cheques are frequently used in scams, however I want to clear up some other issues.

Once deposited cashiers cheques cannot be stopped or reversed just because the sender wants to. They also won't be denied just because the sender doesn't have enough money in their account.

In fact almost the only way a cashiers cheque can be reversed is If it turns out to be fraudulent.  This makes the degree of how much you don't trust the sender important. If it was someone you don't know and can't track down then yes, this may well be a fraudulent cheque. If it's just a flakey friend who who think may try to back out of a deal, they are probably not going to do it with a fraudulent cheque. Passing fraudulent cheques will land them in jail, and most friends, flakey or not, won't take that risk.

Comment: Thank you very much DJClayworth !! Me and the person (who paid me) we are both outside the US. the last time this person paid me it was with an international wire. And I always deny to receive checks in the US as it seerms to me a very unsure payment. I give usually to the person the product and later on if the check would be declared to be fraudulent it would be very difficult for me to complain as I am outside the US.

Comment: The check supposedly was made by a young woman living supposedly in the US and has supposedly a bank account with Well Fargo Bank and would be the girlfriend of the persons cousin.

Comment: If you don't know the person personally then the possibility it is counterfeit is very real and fred_dot_u's answer is probably right.

Comment: Online I can watch the COUNTER DEPOSIT sheet and there is my name and my address in the US. And somebody signed with signature and it says SIGN HERE IF CASH RECEIVED FROM DEPOSIT. Is this correct ?      Or should be there the address and name from the person who made the deposit ??

Comment: You can ask another question for that.

Comment: Reaölly ? There are so many fraudulent checks in the US ???

Comment: Ok I will do that !! Thanx

Comment: I put already a new question !!

Answer (score 0):

If you have no idea why money was deposited in your bank, do not use the money.

It could be fraudulent, it could also be a mistake. The invariable ending to both root causes is the bank will need to take that money away. Note the anomalous balance and notify your bank. You can also notify the bank the check originates from and they can begin an investigation on their end.

You don't, or shouldn't, have any liability unless you spend that money. Fraudulent checks and money are identified and handled by law enforcement.

Comment: While "unexpected deposit" does generate questions, this particular question says nothing of the sort.  They know who gave them the check, they know what it was intended to pay for, they presented it to their bank.  OP isn't worried about a mistake, only about fraud.

Comment: Yes Ben Voigt that is right. I am in the uncomfortable situation that my client is asking me to give to him what he paid with a cashier check. And once he walks away how later on I can complain ?

Comment: Ben Voigt, yes thats right. Thanx !!

Comment: "asking me to give to him what he paid" -- is always a scam.  Offer to have your bank return the payment (not a payment in the other direction, but a return of the first payment -- then the bank has on record that he's already been given his money back)

Comment: @BenVoigt I think OP actually meant to say "give to him what he paid *for*". In another comment, OP said "give to him the product he bought".

Comment: @nanoman: Ahh, what a difference that extra word makes!